# Text fit the image size

Tags: css, html, image, jquery-cycle

I have a list of images, use the [jquery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to view these images.
To the right of this image, a text is displayed..

The problem is that images have different widths, and would like the text was well matched to this image, always leaving a space just 6px away from the image.
Look at the page.
http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br/Project/Details?ProjectID=102

Answer (score 0):

I would set the `width` of the text `div` to the maximum allowed (i.e., the biggest it could be when placed beside the largest picture) and then `float:left` so that the text butts up against the pics.  You could set the `margin-left` to `6px` or something similar.  You may need to `float:left` the pics as well.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the jquery cycle plugin fixes the size of div where you will find the photo.

Making it impossible so I use the float: left.

I was thinking about using a javascript to change the size of the div whenever you change the picture. Adjusting the size of the div for the photo size, so the text would automatically align.